# Undefined index/variable

Tags: php

#### "Notice: Undefined index: size in C:\Nginx\html\default.php on line 3"

I'm getting this error whenever I try opening my new game website. Does someone here have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<?php
$size = $_GET["size"];

/** Default dimensions **/
$width = "960";
$height = "550";

/** Show **/
switch($size) {
    default:
        break;
    case 'large':
        $width = "1185";
        $height = "679";
        break;
    case 'huge':
        $width = "1792";
        $height = "1027";
        break;
    case 'tiny':
        $width = "706";
        $height = "405";
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: dupe of many many questions. also, it's a PHP notice, not an error. There is a significant difference

Comment: After you fix that error as answered by vollie, be sure to move the default case to the end of the switch. PHP evaluates them in order so when at the top, the default will always apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't have size set in your request; thus, the index `'size'` in variable `$_GET` is not set (i.e. undefined). If you request like so `default.php?size=large` it should be gone (if you don't do anything to unset it elsewhere).

Additionally you really should check whether it's set or not with somehting like:

```
$size = isset($_GET["size"]) ? $_GET["size"] : 'normal';
```

which will check if `size=something` is in your query and if it's not will default to `'normal'`.